# UIButton Selector Not Called in ARC

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, automatic-ref-counting, selector

I have two classes, a `View` and a `ViewController.` The `View` creates a button as follows:

```
_button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height)];
[_button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_learn_focus_pad"] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_button addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_someView addSubview:_button];
```

In the `ViewController`, after I instantiated the view in `loadView`, I add a selector to is as follows:

```
[view.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The selector is not being called. I tried to `NSLog` in the `ViewController` the button's position and it printed out a zero. I suspect that ARC is releasing the button. `_button` however, is a `strong` pointer (`@property`). So I am not sure why this is happening.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Why are you passing `nil` as the selector for `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`? This is invalid, and I'm surprised it's not throwing a parameter assertion.

Comment: Also, you're setting an image for an invald state. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is 1<<6, while you probably meant to use `UIControlStateHighlighted` which is just 1.

Comment: `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is valid. Its when you touch the button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not utilizing the proper getter/setter methods generated by the property synthesis.  If you just change the first line to:

```
self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height)];
```

It will properly retain the pointer

Comment: Oh.. so why accessing the ivar directly does not retain the pointer properly?

Comment: Actually, the same problem persists. I replaced all `_button` with `self.button` and it still does not work.

Comment: When you write code like `self.button = [[UIButton alloc] init];` you are using the automatically generated `setButton` method whether you realize it or not.  When you just do `_button = [[UIButton alloc] init];` it is just setting the address to your pointer variable, and does not automatically increment the retain count of the button you created

Comment: @Nayefc it is possible you aren't retaining the button's parent view, or the view itself. I can't really tell what the problem is without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I got it - had another problem but your answer was also right (I had two problems).
Thanks